# Why is the Exclude utility type not working as expected in combination with mapped conditional types on enums in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, enums, conditional-types, mapped-types

Just to give a little bit of context: I'm building a quite complicated form with conditional required values that depend on what has been selected in previous inputs.

Therefore, I made the following object that tells whether an input should be required or not:

```
enum IssueType {
  Error = "Error",
  Advice = "Advice",
}

enum Category {
  Software = "Software",
  Hardware = "Hardware",
  Other = "Other",
}

const inputNames = {
  issueType: "issueType",
  concerning: "concerning",
  serialNumber: "serialNumber",
  errorCode: "errorCode",
} as const;
```

---

```
const conditions: Conditions = {
  [IssueType.Error]: {
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~> Property 'Other' is missing in type ...
    [Category.Software]: {
      [inputNames.concerning]: true,
      [inputNames.serialNumber]: true,
      [inputNames.errorCode]: true,
    },
    [Category.Hardware]: {
      [inputNames.concerning]: true,
      [inputNames.serialNumber]: true,
      [inputNames.errorCode]: true,
    }
  },
  [IssueType.Advice]: {
    [Category.Software]: {
      [inputNames.concerning]: true,
      [inputNames.serialNumber]: true,
      [inputNames.errorCode]: true,
    },
    [Category.Hardware]: {
      [inputNames.concerning]: true,
      [inputNames.serialNumber]: true,
      [inputNames.errorCode]: true,
    },
    [Category.Other]: {
      [inputNames.concerning]: true,
      [inputNames.serialNumber]: true,
      [inputNames.errorCode]: true,
    }
  }
};
```

Now my question is what would the type (`Conditions` in the snippet above) of `conditions` look like. I have tried this:

```
type Conditions = {
  [K in IssueType]: {
    [K in IssueType extends IssueType.Error
      ? Exclude<Category, Category.Other>
      : Category]: {
      [K in Exclude<
        keyof typeof inputNames,
        typeof inputNames.issueType
      >]: boolean;
    };
  };
};
```

but the `Exclude` of `Category.Other` doesn't work. It should only be a mandatory property if it's parent's object key is of type `IssueType.Error`. What am I doing wrong here?

Also I want to avoid (if possible) [Nullable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#nullable-types) like that for instance:

```
type Conditions = {
  [K in IssueType]: {
    [K in Category]?: {
      [K in Exclude<
        keyof typeof inputNames,
        typeof inputNames.issueType
      >]: boolean;
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second level of the object, you should reference `K` (from one level up) instead of `IssueType`. To do this, you cannot name the key type with `K` for all levels.

Here's one where I renamed `K`'s with `A`, `B`, and `C` for clarity:

```
type Conditions = {
  [A in IssueType]: {
    [B in A extends IssueType.Error
      ? Exclude<Category, Category.Other>
      : Category]: {
      [C in Exclude<
        keyof typeof inputNames,
        typeof inputNames.issueType
      >]: boolean;
    };
  };
};
```

Check the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAkgznMwAqBPADsKBvAUFKAUQCdiB7YqAXigCITzjaAafKAQQBMA3ASwGMsNWlz6CWuAL65coSFADCAQwAuwAOYVUONgGUyAMxUB3JcSF19R0+YkEAEmc42LtR8WdngdqAHkVABbAlML+QUys0rj8ZCBwKlC8IOhgKgByShDAcNQ6BLwISGiYAFx0BYgoGN6sBDEggsQgSepltPWNzSDqPnDBvEoANmmQAEbBbX3EA8NjwT7BjApknMBtixTLqxKSUEo59fEA3DIq1YqxnLwqvLE5NHgEANoA0okgsIVVmAC6ZY8EKCvd6fSrFLDAAAeahAnBy8DB1QAdAwKGxAVAAPxESH8QZgVYAHmUak0xFQzEUqg0WiRYWCAD50YCyiSaeS-nkMUC3kkcXiCcBCcyMQBrYCoQxQM6YKVJFLpTLZWrcggy4By5KpDJZOBIipFaoiqAMzmjMhkQbAJQgE4YyR2qAOqQnXDqi6w663OIAfQUvgASgHCApkIQACK5AFPdgghGG37-ZlPABCINjUJhcNBCeAKNIaNV2MIuPxRLZZIpVNJtPpxCZqtZ1MrnIBGKeChBJYFRONBHFkoM0uqmoVOuVfeHsqH8u1Sr1Bu+wGNprK5st1ttzOdBGdzuidwS9SuNzurMuXrufsDwdDEajbCe8aX+cYreTFdpVhMXnfqqes6KrqSIdMEXTqJyKjEEgKrtoB456lMMwjBA4zEJB0HALBgIAVqQHZEiGzEFswAYTB27YR2za0u4njmH+3K4WO84gbEnQtGRWHGkxc7AUhQwoWhnHYc88EsURJHCdubCSCqT5fOCSKiAIpFJu2n7kki34uAxcF4QhrENGBHFlFB5H-mJfH9AJczoaZmEiUClkERJKyqdKDkUR+1GabROlqYxzl6qBTQmR55mBfpLH8bMqHBFJFlRcBrmrAlgKyd5NaaXWuk4UFhnsd0aV6cxVnTDZcV2eFXGJaVLkFsRbnFU6MkukAA).